# Question regarding the construction of Riemannian metrics

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I have problems with the proof why every manifold admits a Riemannian metric. 
If the manifold $M$ has an atlas given by sets $U_i$, we can take a subordinate partition of unity $\{\phi_i\}_i$. Then $\sum \phi_i g_i$, where $g_i$ is the standard metric on $U_i \tilde = \mathbb R^n$,  defines a riemannian metric.

I don't understand why this is well defined. Isn't there some transformation condition we need to to check when switching charts on their overlap?

Comment: Inner products (or positive definite bilinear forms) form a convex cone over the reals.  Specifically, if $g_{1}$ and $g_{2}$ are inner products on a vector space $V$ and $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\alpha, \beta > 0$, then $g = \alpha g_{1} + \beta g_{2}$ is also an inner product.  

On the overlaps, the inner product at a particular point is defined by the sum of inner products, but as you move out of the overlap $U_{i} \cap U_{j}$ to $U_{i}$ or $U_{j}$ (respectively), the contribution of $g_{i}$ or $g_{j}$ (respectively) tapers off to zero, leaving you with a well-defined metric.

Comment: I understand what the definition does. I have the following problem: When for example defining a section by local functions, we still need to check if the sections glue to a global section ($s_i=g_{ij} s_j$). Why is that not the case here, resp how can I see that such a criterion this is fulfilled?

Comment: We're not trying to check that locally-defined sections patch compatibly. We're just summing locally defined Riemannian metrics, and the sum of positive definite bilinear forms with nonnegative coefficients [given by the partition of unity] is again a positive definite bilinear form.

Comment: To me it seems that we cannot sum locally defined sections though, as we would be able to construct sections without zeros for any bundle. So what is the difference?

Comment: Maybe the confusion is related to what is actually being summed.  The local sections $g_{i}$ are local sections of the bundle of symmetric, positive definite (0,2) tensors.  But $\phi_{i}g_{i}$ is a **global** section of the bundle of $(0, 2)$ tensors.  So the summation is a sum of global sections of the bundle of $(0, 2)$ tensors (none of which are necessarily positive definite) that are pieced together in such a way as to form a global section of the bundle of symmetric, positive definite (0, 2) tensors.

Comment: If you try to apply the same technique to construct a global section $v$ of an arbitrary (fiber subbundle of a) vector bundle, you run into the issue that $\phi_1 v_1 + \phi_2 v_2$ could vanish even when $\phi_i > 0$ and $v_i \ne 0$. It is only because we are working with a very particular bundle (the positive symmetric 2-tensors) that this construction works, thanks to the convexity property THW mentions.

Comment: @THW thank, that was very helpful.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Couldn't I just choose the local sections to be constant?